# Xcode Project splash screen images location pointing to wrong location

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I moved my Xcode project to another mac . When i build it,  its throwing an error which shows previous location of splash screen images saying 'No such file or directory'. My splash screen images are in the Resources folder. Where should i change the path to the current location of splash images?

Comment: Have you tried to run cordova build?

Comment: its throwing the same error saying 'No such file or directory'

Comment: When you open the Resource folder in Xcode, are the files there, or are they red? If red, then add the files to your Xcode project.